# Link containers to a running container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to know if I can link Docker containers to a running container. I am running this command on a server:

docker run -d -u jenkins --name appdev-jenkins --network=host --memory="8g" -p 80:8080 -p 443:443 -p 50000:50000 -v "/opt/jenkins":/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  jenkinsci/blueocean

I want to be able to link another Jenkins instance as an agent to the original Jenkins instance. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
docker run -d --link appdev-jenkins --name second-jenkins [other params]
```